# Why ngIf's condition with enum value always returns false

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use enum value in `ngIf` condition, but it's always evaluated to `false`.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf='action'>

    <td *ngIf="action==action.EDIT">
      <button (click)="actionClick(action.EDIT,data.id)">EDIT</button>
    </td>
    <td *ngIf="">
      <button (click)="actionClick(action.DELETE,data.id)">DELETE</button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

```ts
@Input() public action: Action;

Action: typeof Action;
```

Comment: can you please share `ts` code.

Comment: How this `Action` looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component, create a property and assign your enum :

`enumAction = Action`

In your template :

`*ngIf='action === enumAction.EDIT'`